# How can i asyncronously download images from a list of urls in python?

Tags: python

I have no real idea of how to do something like this. I'm using urllib2 to download the images, and as the image names are stored in the URL. I've already made one synchronously,

Comment: [Thread pool](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy)?

Comment: requests-futures? asyncio w/requests?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example

Try this, just follow the example. Almost the same.